# Git Connection Refused with Git Clone. How to reconnect with correct Credentials

Tags: git, version-control

I was attempting to Git Clone a remote repository in the network.

It prompted with the username and password of my local PC.   Because I had
no password in my machine, I left the password blank.

Now whenever I attempt to git clone, it refuses to connect to my PC on port 22.

I've since changed my account to have a password, but I don't know how to reconnect with correct credentials in the Git account.  (I also didn't know having a password was required).

How do I reset the connection?

Comment: Where does the remote repo located, in your local machine? And what's the repo URL did you use for `git clone`?

Comment: the remote repo is in a computer connected through the local network.  Usually i access it via remote desktop but I wanted to add version control since I actively monitor problems in the system

Comment: the repo url I use is the IP address of the network computer, that is the IPv4 address.  I can access it because if I use the URL (e.g. 192.x.x.x/system_name), I can access it

Comment: So can you clone the git repo by the URL with IP address successful now?

Comment: no its still not working

Comment: What's the OS does the remote repo located?

Comment: Windows.  The Rails installer was a bundle for the OS

Comment: I added the answer to clone from another windows machine, and you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

> on port 22.

That means your URL of the remote repo you are trying to clone is an SSH one, not an HTTPS one.

```
 git@aserver:auser/arepo.git
```

In that case, this has nothing to do with your password, but with your ability to create an SSH key and register your public key on the server side.
Here is [an example for GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

Comment: I installed RailsInstaller in the remote machine and it automated setup for Git.   And when I tried SSH the connection timed out.  How do I correct this?

Comment: @PatrickSilva Rails installer has nothing to do with a Git server: what is your git server? Or are you relying on SSH on your remote server to access your remote Git repo?

Comment: The remote repository is located in one of the computers connected via local network.   Git is bundled in RailsInstaller and after installation it automated the creation of the keys.   I'm also not sure how to check if I'm using SSH to access my remote Git repo.  I may have skipped several steps as I was new to deploying a remote repo

Comment: I'm new to the set up so I might not have the right information on how to set up a remote repository

Comment: ` I'm also not sure how to check if I'm using SSH to access my remote Git rep` what is the remote URL you are using for cloning the repo?

Comment: " Git is bundled in RailsInstaller and after installation it automated the creation of the keys": do you have a link to an online documentation which illustrates that?

Comment: The RailsInstaller website includes Git as part of the bundle.  But I don't know where the documentation is, it just automated.   I also use the IP address of the network computer where the remote repo is located

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below steps to clone a git repo from another machine.

Assume the remote git repo locates in PC1 `C:\repo\myrepo` and you want to clone in PC2. Detail steps as below:

#### 1.   Share the folder of the remote repo

In PC1, share the remote repo’s folder `myrepo` from directory `C:\repo`.

#### 2.   Open the share folder from PC2

In PC2, open the share folder from PC by `\\IPforPC1\repo\myrepo`. For the first time, it will pop up the window to enter user name and password to access to PC1.

#### 3.   Clone the remote repo to PC2

Make sure `\\IPforPC1\repo\myrepo` is accessible in PC2, then use the git repo URL as `file:////IPforPC1/repo/myrepo`. So you can clone by executing:

```
git clone file:////IPforPC1/repo/myrepo
```